# Are there any benefits for a disabled individual living in California? (green card holder)

Tags: usa, greencard, benefits, california

In the country I'm coming from there are many benefits given to disabled people (depends on the severity), such as not paying income tax, monthly assistance in the form of a stipend, free public transportation, etc.

Are there similar benefits for a US permanent resident living in California (San Francisco in particular)? Also, are there any official bodies of the State/Government whose purpose is to help disabled people in general?

Comment: I am no expert, but I think that except for perhaps the stipend the other things you listed are not available.

Comment: Define "disabled?" Answers might be easier for specific disabilities...

Comment: Disabled as in a person sitting in a wheelchair.

Comment: Something else to consider:  If anyone signed an affidavit of support to bring you here you're ineligible for means-tested government benefits until you have worked for 10 years.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: Not sure I understand. I got the green card via the lottery, but I am moving to SF to work in SV.

Comment: @danieljackson Ok, you're one of the few that isn't subject to the restriction on means-tested benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The laws and benefits available for persons with Disabilities are convoluted and multi-leveled.  There are federal regulations such as [Americans with Disabilities Act](http://www.ada.gov) which provides mostly for non-discrimination and requirement for accessibility in transport, housing, workplace, etc.  Then there is an [SSDI](http://www.ssa.gov/disability/), which gives persons with disabilities income if they meet some criteria that you can research further.

Then there are state regulations and benefits, which for California you can probably find on [Disability Rights California](http://www.disabilityrightsca.org/pubs/PublicationsHealthBenefits.htm) but it will take some doing since there are a lot of initiatives.

The there are county and Local regulations which in San Francisco are handled by the [Mayor's Office on Disability](http://www.sfgov2.org/index.aspx?page=386) which can give you even more benefits and rights.